How does one apply loadings of a PLSR model to a data point?
Problem:
I am having difficulty understanding how I would apply the loadings of my latent variables to each individual observation in a dataset.
Current understanding:
I have a model that has used the SIMPLS algorithm and maximized the covariance of predictor variables for each latent variable. This latent variable then has a coefficient, but it also has loadings for each independent variable inside of it's definition.
I want to reproject all of my observations to the base space that is used in the PLSR model. I believe this means that each individual data point will be reprojected along the 'new' axes in a redefined space. To do this, I am unsure if I use the x or y loadings, as I am working in Python.
Is it correct that the x_loadings are the loadings within each latent variable, while the y_loadings are the coefficients of each latent variable?
Example
blood pressure ~ weight + cholesterol:
bp = blood pressure
wt = weight
chl = cholesterol
b = intercept
wl_'x' = weight latent variable
LV_1 = 0.5wt + 0.8chl
LV_2 = -0.5wt + 0.9chl
bp = b + w_1LV1 + w_2Lv2
In this example, the x_loadings would be the coefficients of the terms in the LV_'x' functions and the y_loadings would be the coefficients of the terms in the bp function.
Is this the correct understanding?
